# Call to a Node.js dependency complains about an unexpected token for a promise

Tags: node.js, syntax, promise, unexpected-token

On a Raspberry Pi 3 I can build a dependency without any errors.
But when I attempt to use it in my code I get an error about the syntax and an unexpected token.

I can build the following dependency for Jive-SDK: https://github.com/jivesoftware/jive-sdk
using

> npm install jive-sdk

But when I call that dependency from my project during the install it errors out.

> /home/pi/jive-project/raspi/node_modules/jive-sdk/jive-sdk
>
> api/lib/util/jiveutil.js:708
>
> return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
>
> ```
>                                     ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>
> at require (module.js:380:17)
>
> at Object. (/home/pi/jive-
>
> project/raspi/node_modules/jive-sdk/jive-sdk-api/api.js:130:16)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

I've tried this with several versions of Node.JS 7.10.0 on up to the latest but always get this error.

Am I missing something in my environment?

exports.util = require('./lib/util/jiveutil');

Comment: Nodejs 7? That sounds ancient. Does it support arrow function syntax yet?

Comment: Yes, this is clearly a very old project with a last contribution in 2017 (the project, not the node version).  Node 7.10.0 was released 5.2.17 so it should support arrow function syntax.